# How to configure many-to-many relations to show in text field (like tags)

Tags: forms, symfony, many-to-many, doctrine-orm

I have a website for movie reviews with movie review form, where movies have many-to-many relationship to actors.

Now I want to offer a text field (in future with autocomplete), where I can add actors to the movie.

I have this code: `$builder->add('actors','textarea');`, but it offers a text field with following weird prefilled text content:

```
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@0000000051c7ab6e00000000d586d059
```

How can I represent this as a text field where I can add actors (like tags)?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html). That should point you in the right direction for this kind of functionality.

You are getting that content in the text area because the symfony2 form element is pre-filling it with the `getActors()` method on your movie entity.